# Mysql optimisation tool

Tags: mysql

Can anyone suggest a good MYSQL optimization tool which helps in finding the bottlenecks in a long query and hence help in optimization?? I am looking for a query profiler.

thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "MySQL optimization tool"? That is not a common term. Please describe your problem in more detail, otherwise we'll have to close the question.

Comment: in keeping with good practices at StackOverflow, please upvote any answer that has helped you and finally mark the 'one' answer that has helped you the most as 'correct' (green check).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You mean Query Optimization? I guess `EXPLAIN <query>` is excellent in giving hits as to where the bottlenecks are. After which redefine you indexes & ...

**UPDATE1:** You could check out - **[MySQL optimization tools](http://mediakey.dk/~cc/mysql-performance-monitoring-and-optimization-tools/)**

**UPDATE2:** After digging up in my code, I see that I used to do 2 things for query optimization.

1. **Turn on Slow Query Log -** MySQL can record expensive SQL queries in the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html). You can define your expectations in seconds using parameter `long_query_time`.
2. **mysqldumpslow command** - After logging is turned on you can analyze the log contents using `mysqldumpslow` command. `mysqldumpslow /path/to/your/mysql-slow-queries.log -t 10`. This will show you top 10 performance killers. For each statement in the output you can see the number of identical calls, execution time in seconds, rows affected and the statement itself.

Comment: should work. the query is running is it not? if in doubt make it run for some query which has a value