# Information regarding query profiler

Tags: database

Does anyone have an information about a good query profiler?? By query i mean about 5 page search query.The profiler should be such as which gives the bottleneck in the query.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql optimisation tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012970/mysql-optimisation-tool)

Comment: Ironically, the OP does appear to have accepted an answer on the duplicate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the database engine you use.

If it's Sybase, then use [`set statistics`](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/ptallbk/@Generic__BookTextView/52422) (io, time) and `set queryplan on`.

In MySQL, you can do `EXPLAIN <query>`. More approaches are in this blog entry: "[MySQL Performance Monitoring and Optimization Tools](http://mediakey.dk/~cc/mysql-performance-monitoring-and-optimization-tools/)".

In MS SQL Server use [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966515.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can use [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) Query Profiler feature... [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) is very simple and easy to use MySQL GUI tool with loads of powerfull features... Hope it helps...

[image: Query Profiler Screenshot]